# How to use strsplit on SparkDataFrame

Tags: r, azure-databricks, sparkr, strsplit

I am taking my first steps in the `Azure Databricks` world and therefore I have to learn how to use `SparkR`.

[I am coming from `data.table`]

Although I have read a lot of documentation, I think something escapes me on SparkDataFrame.

To create a new column, I learned that we can do something like :

```
sdf$new <- sdf$old * 0.5
```

But if I want to use a basic function, I got an error and I can't figure out why :

```
sdf <- sql("select * from database.table")
sdf$new <- strsplit(sdf$old, "-")[1]

Error in strsplit((sdf$old), "-") : 
  non-character argument
Some(<code style = 'font-size:10p'> Error in strsplit((sdf$old), &quot;-&quot;): non-character argument </code>)
```

What am I missing ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `strsplit` you need to use Spark specific functions that you can find in the [Spark R API documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/index.html).  Specifically, you need to use `split_string` function, combined with `getItem` function (please note that you need to specify `L` to force number be an integer):

```r
new_df <- withColumn(sdf, "new_id", getItem(split_string(sdf$old, ","), 0L))
```

Comment: Your detailed explanations help me see more clearly. I had started to discover the Spark  specific functions, but I believe that I would never have found ```getItem```. SparkR seems like a new language to me !

Comment: For introduction into Spark, I recommend free book - Learning Spark, 2ed - you can get it from Databricks site